# Regex, Select characters between multiple brackets

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string:

```
john<str> name2, doe<str>  name1
```

where str can be string of arbitrary length

I want to select and replace '< str >'  and '< str >'  with an empty character, such that I get:

```
john name1, doe name2
```

I have the following:

```
new_string = re.sub('<.*>', '', astring, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

However this is giving me:

```
john name1
```

Comment: Can `str` contains `<` and `>` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Make your regex non greedy by adding a `?` after the `*`

```
astring = 'john<str> name2, doe<str>  name1'
re.sub('<.*?>', '', astring, flags=re.DOTALL)
# 'john name2, doe  name1'
```

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you, this is correct. That's a reluctant quantifier.